# Информация о компьютере

Tags: ip, php, javascript

Здравствуйте мастера! Надо написать скрипт который при заходе на сайт будет записывать в файл ip.txt данные например:

```
1* 13:55 23.11.11 Windows Xp SP3 Opera 127.0.0.1 Beeline Stavropol Russia<br/>
2* 10:16 22.11.11 Linux Mandriva Mazila 127.0.0.1 MTS Moscow Russia<br/>
```

Что то вроде этого должно получиться... При каждом заходе на страницу
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А вот подождали бы подольше... =)

Comment: Если на сервере стоит Apache, то можно использовать директивы [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) и [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) для вывода в логи записей требуемого формата.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$log = "ip.txt"; //файл для логов
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //айпи адрес
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //лузерагент
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); //дата в формате March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm

$fp = fopen($log, 'a'); //открываем фаел на дозапись (в конец файла)
fwrite($fp, $date2.$ip.$agent."\n"); //пишем дату-переменную в которой айпи и агент
fclose($fp); //закрываем фаел

?>
```

//подробней (для других параметров) гугли содержание массива $_SERVER, бери данные оттуда и записывай в фаел. Будут вопросы, пиши тут.

Comment: ну, ещё бы файлы писать на каждый день и вообще красота будет )

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, чтобы получить время на компе юзера, надо использовать не функцию **"date"**,
а **"localtime"**. **"Date"** возвращает дату на сервере, где установлен php, а **"localtime"** - массив из
9 элементов. Подробнее в мануале - http://www.php.su/functions/?localtime